# Binary Tree using a record structure

Tags: python, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, record

I have written this program from the text book Cambridge International A & AS level, but I cannot find where I have gone wrong. It is for a binary tree to be implemented using a record structure. It must use a record structure as the exams use these.

When the program runs, it only lets me add one item, even though the array allows for up to 8 items?

Here is the code:

```
NULLPOINTER = -1

class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Data= ""
        self.LeftPointer = NULLPOINTER
        self.RightPointer = NULLPOINTER

def InialiseTree():
    Tree = [TreeNode() for i in range(8)]
    RootPointer = NULLPOINTER
    FreePtr = 0
    for Index in range(7):
        Tree[Index].leftPointer = Index+1
    return (Tree, RootPointer, FreePtr)

def InsertNode(Tree, RootPointer, FreePtr, NewItem):
    if FreePtr !=NULLPOINTER:#there is space in the array, 
        NewNodePtr = FreePtr #take node from free list and store there
        Tree[NewNodePtr].Data = NewItem
        FreePtr=Tree[FreePtr].LeftPointer
        Tree[NewNodePtr].LeftPointer= NULLPOINTER
        if RootPointer ==NULLPOINTER:
            RootPointer = NewNodePtr
        else:
            ThisNodePtr = RootPointer
            while ThisNodePtr != NULLPOINTER:
                PreviousNodePtr=ThisNodePtr
                if Tree[ThisNodePtr].Data>NewItem:
                    TurnedLeft = True
                    ThisNodePtr=Tree[ThisNodePtr].LeftPointer
                else:
                    TurnedLeft = False
                    ThisNodePtr=Tree[ThisNodePtr].RightPointer
            if TurnedLeft:
                Tree[PreviousNodePtr].LeftPointer=NewNodePtr
            else:
                Tree[PreviousNodePtr].RightPointer=NewNodePtr
    else:
        print("No space for more data")
    return (Tree, RootPointer, FreePtr)
            
def TraverseTree(Tree, RootPointer):
  if RootPointer != NULLPOINTER:
    TraverseTree(Tree, Tree[RootPointer].LeftPointer)
    print(Tree[RootPointer].Data)
    TraverseTree(Tree, Tree[RootPointer].RightPointer)


def GetOption():
  print("1: add data")
  print("2: find data")
  print("3: traverse data")
  print("4: end program")
  option = input("Enter your choice: ")
  return (option)

def FindNode(Tree, RootPointer, SearchItem):
  ThisNodePtr= RootPointer
  while ThisNodePtr!= NULLPOINTER and Tree[ThisNodePtr].Data!=SearchItem:
    if Tree[ThisNodePtr].Data>SearchItem:
      ThisNodePtr = Tree[ThisNodePtr].LeftPointer
    else:
      ThisNodePtr = Tree[ThisNodePtr].RightPointer
  return (ThisNodePtr)
  
#main program
Tree, RootPointer, FreePtr = InialiseTree()
Option=GetOption()
while Option !=4:
  if Option == "1":
    Data = input("Enter the value: ")
    Tree, RootPointer, FreePtr = InsertNode(Tree, RootPointer, FreePtr, Data)
    TraverseTree(Tree, RootPointer)
  elif Option=="2":
    Data = input("Enter search value: ")
    ThisNodePtr= FindNode(Tree, RootPointer, Data)
    if ThisNodePtr==NULLPOINTER:
      print("Value not found")
    else:
      print("VAlue found at ", ThisNodePtr)
    print(RootPointer, FreePtr)
    for i in range (8):
      print(i, "  ", Tree[i].LeftPointer, "  ", Tree[i].Data, Tree[i].RightPointer, "  " )
  elif Option =="3":
    TraverseTree(Tree, RootPointer)  
  Option = GetOption()
```

I am expecting to be able to add 8 items and then to be able to search for an item. I have gone through the code trying to work out where the error is but I cannot find it

Comment: You have a typo: In `InialiseTree` you assign to `leftPointer`, creating a new attribute for each node. It should be `LeftPointer`. Voting to close.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate this. I am new to teaching the course and I do not have anyone else in my department to support me